# Showing specific records in mysql according to the link clicked

Tags: php, mysql

When I click one of the following links, I want to go to categorie.php, but depending on what link I click, I want to show a different kind of information. So the query would be if I click the first link for example in categorie.php: `SELECT * from advertenties where maat=50;`

```
<a href=categorie.php>50(0-1 mnd)</a><br>
<a href=categorie.php>56(1-2 mnd)</a><br>
<a href=categorie.php>62(2-4 mnd)</a><br>
<a href=categorie.php>68(4-6 mnd)</a><br>
<a href=categorie.php>74(6-9 mnd)</a><br>
<a href=categorie.php>80(9-12 mnd)</a><br>
<a href=categorie.php>86(1-1,5 jaar)</a><br>
```

Now I have no idea how to get the value of the link

I did make a php page that looks alot like this but is a little bit different which looks like this:

```
while ($thread = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
echo <<<EOT
<table>
<th><a href=thread.php?thread_id={$thread['thread_id']}> {$thread['title']} </a></th>
</table>
EOT;
}
```

But this is just showing all the topics of a forum.

At my page I want to show some standard values, and show everything that has that value as a tag. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: This is core/basic PHP, and something you need to learn yourself.

Comment: @MarcB Maybe I am just thinking too difficult... Is it really that easy?

Comment: Yep. It is. PHP sends information to the browser. User selects some of that info (click on it, enter into a form field, whatever) and sends it back to the server, server builds new page based on that information.

Comment: @MarcB ow duh of course. sorry I just forgot to think for a minute.

Comment: @Loko **Unrelated**: no need to be offended, if your post was corrected: maybe nitpicking, but the right spelling is [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/) and [PHP](http://php.net/), and "[a lot](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alot)" is spelled separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a parameter to the url:

`<a href="categorie.php?cat=50">50(0-1 mnd)</a><br>`

Then access count using `$_GET['cat']`

Within your sql query use the value of cat to access the data you want:

Assuming your using PDO

```
<?php 
$sql = 'SELECT * from advertenties WHERE maat = :cat';
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':cat'=>$_GET['cat']));

$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```